# How can i reorganise powershell's compare-object output?

Tags: powershell, compare

I'm comparing 2 CSV with the compare-object cmdlet :

```
Compare-object $CSV1 $CSV2 -property Header, Value -passthru | sort-object Header
```

After comparing 2 CSVs, i ended up with the following output :

```
Header              Value           SideIndicator
-------             -----           -------------
String1             Value 1             <=
String1             Value 2             =>
String2             Value 3             <=
String2             Value 4             =>
String3             Value 5             =>
String4             Value 6             <=
```

I'd like to reorganise it to the following format

```
Header1             Old Value       New Value
------              ---------       ---------
String1             Value 1         Value 2
String2             Value 3         Value 4
String3             NA              Value 5
String4             Value 6         NA
```

Is that doable in powershell ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
$a = Compare-Object (Import-Csv 'C:\temp\f1.csv')  (Import-Csv 'C:\temp\f2.csv')  -property Header,Value
$a | Group-Object -Property Header | % { New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{Header=$_.name;newValue=$_.group[0].Value;oldValue=$_.group[1].Value}}
```

Comment: Answer doesn't give an exact result that OP asked for - for all unmatched lines Group array has only a single element (0) and because of that Value would always be placed into a newValue column, while oldValue column would remain empty. I'm also not sure about the order of elements in Group array, so it's necessary to check SideIndicator property of each element.

Answer (score 1):

As i indicated by [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446034/how-can-i-reorganise-powershells-compare-object-output/17447708#comment113113621_17447708), [JPBlanc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17447708/5468905) has some flaws. Here's an improved one based on his code:

```bsh
$CSV1 = Import-Csv "C:\temp\f1.csv"
$CSV2 = Import-Csv "C:\temp\f2.csv"
$Diff = Compare-Object $CSV1 $CSV2 -property Header, Value
function Value-On-SideIndicator($Object, $SideIndicator) {
    $Group = $Object.Group | ? {$_.SideIndicator -eq $SideIndicator}
    if ($Group -ne $null) { $Group.Value } else { "NA" }
}
$Diff | Group-Object -Property Header | % {
    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
        Header = $_.Group[0].Value;
        newValue = Value-On-SideIndicator $_ "=>";
        oldValue = Value-On-SideIndicator $_ "<="
    }
} | Format-Table Header, oldAmount, newAmount -AutoSize
```

**Powershell 7**: (using null-coalescing operator)

```bsh
$CSV1 = Import-Csv "C:\temp\f1.csv"
$CSV2 = Import-Csv "C:\temp\f2.csv"
$Diff = Compare-Object $CSV1 $CSV2 -property Header, Value
$Diff | Group-Object -Property Header | % {
    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
        Header = $_.Group[0].Value;
        newValue = ($_.Group | ? {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"}).Value ?? "NA";
        oldValue = ($_.Group | ? {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="}).Value ?? "NA"
    }
} | Format-Table Header, oldAmount, newAmount -AutoSize
```