# powershell compare two files and list their columns with side indicator as match/mismatch

Tags: powershell

I have seen powershell script which also I have in mind. What I would like to add though is another column which would show the side indicator comparators ("==", "<=", "=>") and be named them as MATCH(if "==") and MISMATCH(if "<=" and "=>").
Any advise on how I would do this?

Here is the link of the script (Credits to Florent Courtay)
[How can i reorganise powershell's compare-object output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446034/how-can-i-reorganise-powershells-compare-object-output)

```
$a = Compare-Object (Import-Csv 'C:\temp\f1.csv') (Import-Csv 'C:\temp\f2.csv') -property Header,Value 
    $a | Group-Object -Property Header | % { New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{Header=$_.name;newValue=$_.group[0].Value;oldValue=$_.group[1].Value}}
```

========================================================================

The output I have in mind:

```
Header1             Old Value       New Value    STATUS
------              ---------       --------- -----------
String1             Value 1         Value 2      MATCH
String2             Value 3         Value 4      MATCH
String3             NA              Value 5      MISMATCH
String4             Value 6         NA           MISMATCH
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a self-contained solution; simply replace the `ConvertFrom-Csv` calls with your `Import-Csv` calls:

```
# Sample CSV input.
$csv1 = @'
Header,Value
a,1
b,2
c,3
'@

$csv2 = @'
Header,Value
a,1a
b,2
d,4
'@

Compare-Object (ConvertFrom-Csv $csv1) (ConvertFrom-Csv $csv2) -Property Header, Value |
  Group-Object Header | Sort-Object Name | ForEach-Object {
    $newValIndex, $oldValIndex = ((1, 0), (0, 1))[$_.Group[0].SideIndicator -eq '=>']
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Header = $_.Name
      OldValue = ('NA', $_.Group[$oldValIndex].Value)[$null -ne $_.Group[$oldValIndex].Value]
      NewValue = ('NA', $_.Group[$newValIndex].Value)[$null -ne $_.Group[$newValIndex].Value]
      Status = ('MISMATCH', 'MATCH')[$_.Group.Count -gt 1]
    }
  }
```

The above yields:

```
Header OldValue NewValue Status
------ -------- -------- ------
a      1        1a       MATCH
c      3        NA       MISMATCH
d      NA       4        MISMATCH
```

Note:

- The assumption is that a given `Header` column value appears at most *once* in each input file.
- The `Sort-Object Name` call is needed to sort the output by `Header` values<sup>Thanks, [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings).</sup>
  , because, due to how `Compare-Object` orders its output (right-side-only items first), the order of groups created by `Group-Object` would *not* automatically reflect the 1st CSV's order of header values (`d` would appear before `c`).